# I can not displayin birtday which is formatted in DATE

Tags: php, date

i want to display the customers information who was born between 1980 and 1990. And i tried this but it doesnt work. Can u please help me?

This is my php codes.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "company";


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname)
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM musteri WHERE dogumtarih<'1980-01-01' and 
dogumtarih>'1990-01-01'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+date+between+dates

Comment: You are getting all dates before (<) 1980 and after (>) 1990. That's the opposite of what you say you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change your sql between query as per below solutions:

```
$sql = "SELECT *
FROM musteri
WHERE (dogumtarih BETWEEN '1980-01-01' AND '1990-01-01')";
```

You can find record between two dates.

Hope This Works for you.

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on StackOverflow because they do very little to educate the OP and future readers.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment you should use `between` in query like this

`SELECT * FROM musteri WHERE (dogumtarih BETWEEN '1980-01-01' AND '1990-01-01')`

for more information about comparison operators ([Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html))

Answer (score 1):

Your code is right but there is a logic error there

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM musteri WHERE dogumtarih>'1980-01-01' and 
dogumtarih<'1990-01-01'";
```

you want the birthday to be **after** 1980 and **before** 1990 so this should work fine for you. You just confused the comparison operators.